# php/mysql: update value in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I have a table of horses in a classifieds site.  The fields in question are:

**uniquevalue**  (random alphanumeric given to each horse ad in any given order - same one is applied to between 1 and 6 horse ads; max 6 ads in an order.  This doubles up as the $item_number in the paypal ipn transaction)

**ppconfirmed**  (a 1,0 boolean, default=0, to be switched to 1 when paypal ipn runs on successful transaction)

The paypal ipn script updates a different table in the db with all the appropriate info.  That's running fine.

What I need to happen:  each horse record should have the ppconfirmed value set to 1, for each horse whose uniquevalue field matches the $item_number used in the paypal ipn post.

Hope that makes sense!

Austen

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be any harder than this

`UPDATE yourTable SET ppconfirmed = 1 WHERE uniquevalue = '$item_number'`

Comment: Hiya - if there's only one ad, then that's true (i tested it like that in case it was something else), but if there are more than 2 rows that have the uniquevalue (bad name, i know), then it needs to update all of them.

Comment: And it will update ALL rows that have this matching `uniquevalue`.

Comment: Ha! - Seems I was trying to make life hard for myself...  :-)  Cheers for the help, most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an `UPDATE` statement with `JOIN` clause, very similar to the one described in the first post to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html